# Create iOS build with client's distribution profile

Tags: xcode, app-store, ios-provisioning

I have just finished an iOS app for a client, and have received a copy of their distribution profile (.cer format). I have dragged it into XCode as described in the docs from Apple. Now, I can select that profile for a distribution build, in the build settings for the project, but when I go to the target, I cannot select that profile? Any ideas on how to resolve that?

Also, is this the right way to go to create a distribution build, that the client can submit for approval?

Thanks!
- Lasse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You not only need their iOS Distribution Certificate, but the private key for that certificate as well (a password protected .p12 export from their Keychain will work).

You might want to install the client's certificates in a separate Mac User account as well (which will have its own Keychain), so as not to confuse your Keychain, since yours may already have your own certificates.

Comment: I got the profile in .p12 and a private, and made it work - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need a copy of your client's signing identity.  They can export it as a .p12 file from the keychain manager.